# Looping through $_POST Variable

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that generates some form on the page I have. I also have a table and submit button within the form which all works fine and the data is sent to the next page as intended. Now on the next page I have a PHP code that reads the `$_POST` variable. Here is my code:

```
echo "<form name=\"myForm\" id=\"myForm\" method=\"post\" action=\"\">";
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Group</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qryRes))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input name=\"aName" . $row['id'] . "\" id=\"aName" . $row['id'] . "\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $row['aName'] . "\" /></td>";
    echo "<td><select name=\"gID" . $row['id'] . "\">";
        while($gRow = mysql_fetch_array($grpsQry))
        {
            if($gRow['id'] == $row['groupID'])
                echo "<option id=\"" . $gRow['id'] . "\" selected=\"selected\">" . $gRow['gName'] . "</option>";
            else
                echo "<option id=\"" . $gRow['id'] . "\">" . $gRow['gName'] . "</option>";
        }
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    mysql_data_seek( $grpsQry, 0 );
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submitForm\" value=\"Save\" />";
echo "</form>";
```

Then comes my PHP Code to read the `$_POST`:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitForm']))
{
    print_r($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $x)
        echo $x . "<br />";
}
```

Everything works fine, except that I need to read only the text field in the `foreach` loop as I will generate a query on them and will compare the values I will have with the value returned from the `List` ..

As yuo can see, the `textfield` is named `aName` then the id of the user. I need to read this only. But I will use it to generate a query which will be then compared to the value of the List `gID`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){    
    if(substr($key,0,5) == 'aName')
        echo $value . "<br />"; 
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer to help other guys with your same problem @sikas